# Invoke javascript method from ASP.NET MVC controller using SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am using SignalR in my application in order to be able to automatically invoke one JavaScript method whenever a specific action method of a ASP.NET MVC controller is accessed/hit/invoke. Everything works fine on the first hit. But when I try to hit the controller action second time my `HttpWebRequest` times out. Following is my controller:

```
public class ShowRoomHubController : Controller
{
    public void UpdateDressingRoomData()
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ShowRoomHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.All.acceptGreet();
    }
}
```

My hub is as follow:

```
public class ShowRoomHub : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.hello();
    }

    public void GreetAll()
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.acceptGreet("test now");
    }
}
```

Calling `UpdateDressingRoomData` action from `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpClient` works for first time only then it starts timing out. Here is my console application code (HTTP client):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:81/ShowRoomHub/UpdateDressingRoomData");
var response = request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

Or

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:81/ShowRoomHub/UpdateDressingRoomData").Result;
```

Here is my javascript client side code:

```
    connection = $.hubConnection();

    //Creating proxy
    this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('showRoomHub');

    connection.logging = true;

    //Publishing an event when server pushes a greeting message
    this.proxy.on('acceptGreet', function () {
        //alert('message');
        $rootScope.$emit("acceptGreet", null);
    });

    //Starting connection
    connection.start().done(function () {
        //alert('started');
    });
```

Any idea what's wrong in my code?

Comment: can you paste your client method's code?

Comment: I have added my javascript code too.